# Firebase check if logged in user is writing to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to make sure that every push to the Firebase database is indeed the same person who is logged in. You can intercept requests and change the ID and make it look like somebody else posted it.. How can I prevent this?

This is what I've tried, but it fails `permission denied`:

**EDIT**: added .write

**deleted**

**EDIT2:**
Adding a new question when user is logged in:

```
var newQuestion = Firebase.database().ref("/questions");
var user = Firebase.auth().currentUser;
newQuestion.push({
  title: this.props.question,
  userId: user.uid,
  user: user.displayName,
  time: moment().format(),
  answers: this.props.answers
})
```

What I want is a rule that checks if the logged in user is still the user that is posting the question. In other words, no one can post in your name by 'stealing' your uid.

Rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "questions":{
      "$question_id":{
         ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == newData.child('userId').isString()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /questions/-KTyWyapvfsIzqoe6gmp failed:
>   permission_denied
>   Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
>   Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Comment: There is no write rule so it is default false.

Comment: @AndréKool feel like writing that up in a small answer? Maybe with an example of Greg's security rules, but then fixed.

Comment: I have added `".write": "auth != null"` under `read` but it's still not working

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: That means the user isn't signed in or you're writing to the wrong location. If you're doing this from code, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Starting with an empty jsbin and adding code until you've reproduced the problem is typically a great way to doing so.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my post with more code

Comment: None of the code signs the user in. Instead of doing this interactively, provide the minimum *complete* code that reproduces the problem. As I said in my previous comment: reproducing the problem in a jsbin is an effective way to do so.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The login code has nothing to do with the issue, they're logged in. A jsbin is overkill because I'd have to implement the whole authentication + pushing data.